# Sorting names by alphabetical order: more efficient way

Tags: c, sorting, alphabetical

I'm developing an application and one of the functions is the function sort_books which basically has to sort the name of the books in the file fp by alphabetical order and then writes the books into the file fp2 and prints the names of the books by alphabetical order into the console.

My function is working perfectly with the bubble sort algorithm but to sort 100000 books it tooks approximately 4 minutes, which is way too much time.

Someone knows how I could adapt this code to be way more efficient and quicker?

```
FILE *fp
FILE *fp2;

sort_books(){
struct book books[100000];
struct book b;

//open files

int i = 0;
while (!feof(fp)){

   fread(&b,sizeof(b),1,fp);

       if(feof(fp))
    {
        break;
    }   

    books[i] = b;
        i++;        
}

//number of books in the file
int len = i;

//bubble sort;
int j = 0;

//Bubble sort: sorting algorithm
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<len-1; j++)
        {
           //If the first book should come after the next book in the array
           if(strcmp(books[j].name, books[j+1].name) > 0)
        {
            //swap the books
            struct book temp;
            temp = books[j];
            books[j] = books[j+1];
            books[j+1] = temp;
        }
        }
    }

    //now write each book in the array "books" into the file one by one
    int z;
    for(z=0; z<len; z++)
    {   
        fwrite(&books[z],sizeof(books[z]),1,fp2);
        //test console
        printf("Name: %s \n", books[z].name);
    }

    //close files

    }
```

Comment: Try quick/merge sort?

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Virtually any sort you find will be more efficient than a bubble sort.  Even with a requirement to sort in place, it's much faster and about as easy to step through the list, find the smallest value, and swap that value to first position, then repeat starting from the second element, and so forth; that involves moving just about half as much data (on average) as a bubble sort.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `while (1feof(fp))`, it will not work as you expect because the `EOF` flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond the end of the file. This means you ill iterate the loop once to many. Instead do e.g. `while (fread(...) == sizeof(b))`

Comment: @Zombie : See my updated answer. Please let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: is your question if there is a faster sort than bubble sort?

Comment: @Grady Player: Yes it was but I already implemented the quicksort algorithm and it works perfectly and way faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bubble sort is O(n^2). You could try Quicksort, which is O(nlogn). Essentially, most sorting algorithms are faster than the bubble sort you demonstrated.

[image]

For a list of most common sorting methods, their animations, as well as their implementations, refer to the following page:

http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: Thanks Steve! I'll try to implement the quicksort algorithm.

Comment: @Zombie quicksort is n^2 on already sorted data, you may want to consider that to get good consistency you will need to do a shuffle first, which makes it best case (n log n) (which is included in the graph)... also most standard libraries have a qsort function...

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yes worst case for quicksort is n^2

Comment: @steve the point that I was making is the although other sorting algs have a pathological input... quick sort has the problem with already sorted data, and nearly sorted data, which is a common case...

Comment: @GradyPlayer  I see. That's true.

Comment: I think radix sort can be used